# Getting pdf file as a String from downstream team and now I want to convert that file(that coming as string format) into a zip file

Tags: java, spring-boot, solver

After converting zip file the pdf file content is getting blank, please refer below code

public ResponseEntity createResponseEntityForZipFile (DownloadBill downloadBill) throws Exception ByteArrayOutputStream baos new ByteArrayOutputStream();

File File now File("/Users/nfg/Documents/bksj789.pdf");

File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")); File pdfFile = new File(tempDir, downloadBill.getFileName());

FileUtils.writeStringToFile(pdfFile, downloadBill.getPdfString(), encoding "UTF-8") InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);

try (ZipOutputStream zipout new ZipOutputStream(baos)) { ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(dirsDownload InvoiceBillesponse.getFileName()); zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry):

byte[] bytes= new byte[1024]:

int Length:

while((Length = inputStream.read(bytes)) >= 0) {

zipOut.write(bytes, off: 0, length):

}

zipOut.closeEntry();

inputStream.close();

baos.close();

}

catch (Exception e)

}

OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(pathname: /Users/njh/Documents/again.zip"));

os.write(baos.toByteArray());

os.close();

ByteArrayResource resource new ByteArrayResource(baos.toByteArray());

HttpHeaders httpHeaders new HttpHeaders();

httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT DISPOSITION, headerValue: "attachment; filename=files21.zip");

return ResponseEntity.ok()

.headers(httpHeaders)

.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET STREAN)

.body(resource);

I tried most of thing but none of them got worked

Comment: Please post properly formatted and indented code. Don't just dump your code as ordinary text